# Biblatex, How to make Author First name to be short for Harvard Referencing?

Tags: biblatex, harvard-style

For example:

```
@book{cohen2013statistical,
  title={Statistical power analysis for the behavioral sciences},
  author={Cohen, Jacob},
  year={1988},
  publisher={Routledge},
  edition = {2}
}
```

Outcome:

[image]

It suppose to be:

```
Cohen, J., 2013. Statistical power analysis for the behavioral sciences. Routledge.
```

where the first name become short `Cohen, J.`

Comment: If I remember well, you have to load biblatex with option `giveninits`.

Comment: @Bernard, how to make the given name appear first, then surename. For example: `Kazem, M. L., J. M. Noyes, and N. J. Lieven`. It suppose to be `Kazem, M.L., Noyes, J.M. and Lieven, N.J., ` The first author is fine, second author and third author having problem

Comment: Please -- as usual here -- show us a short compilable tex code building your bibliography! Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ... And add an bib entry to your question you have problems with the second or third author!

Comment: @Mensch, I will create a new question to ask now. Thanks

Comment: You need not to ask a new question, edit this question and add the new infos!

Comment: @aan Since you've asked a new question, we'll close this question as a duplicate. But instead of asking new questions in response to comments, it's much better to edit the question. (And there will be comments on the new question too, since you have posted a code fragment.)

Comment: @Alan Munn, thanks. i just worry too many sub-questions in one main question is not good

Comment: @aan That's generally a good rule of thumb, but if the questions are very closely related (as in this case, it's not usually necessary).